# How to put data in the state in order

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I'd like to ask how to retrieve data through `useEffect()` hook.
The flow I want is as follows.
First, I want to get the 'cards' state, fill the cards with data, and then fill the data through the cardsPromises after that.
But my code couldn't get cards and wordAll, and the empty value came out.
I think it's because the cards are still empty, but I don't know how to operate in order.

```
  const [wordAll, setWordAll] = useState([]);
  const [cards, setCards] = useState([]); 

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http/api/words/", {
        headers: {
          Authorization: cookies.token,
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        setCards(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });

    const cardsPromises = cards.map((contents) =>
      axios.get(
        `http/api/words/detail_list/?contents=${contents.contents}`,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: cookies.token,
          },
        }
      )
    );
    console.log("cards", cards);

    Promise.all(cardsPromises)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("resp", response.data);
        setWordAll(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("err==>", error);
      });
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, `cards` array is still empty in the `useEffect` callback when the fetching the data. I suggest converting to `async`/`await` and waiting for the first fetch to resolve and using *that* value of `cards` for the fetching of the rest of the data.

```
const [wordAll, setWordAll] = useState([]);
const [cards, setCards] = useState([]); 

useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const{ data: cards } = await axios.get(
        "http/api/words/",
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: cookies.token,
          },
        },
      );
      setCards(cards);

      const cardsPromises = cards.map((contents) =>
        axios.get(
          `http/api/words/detail_list/?contents=${contents.contents}`,
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization: cookies.token,
            },
          }
        );
      );
      const wordAllResponse = await Promise.all(cardsPromises);
      const wordAll = wordAllResponse.map(({ data }) => data);
      setWordAll(wordAll);
    } catch (error) {
      // handle any errors, rejected Promises, etc..
    }
  };

  fetchData();
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your 2nd axios call inside a function, and call it after 1st axios call returns.

```js
useEffect(() => {

  const getWords = (cards) => {
    const cardsPromises = cards.map((contents) =>
      axios.get(
        `http/api/words/detail_list/?contents=${contents.contents}`,
        {
          headers: {Authorization: cookies.token}
        }
      )
    );

    Promise.all(cardsPromises)
      .then((response) => {
        setWordAll(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("err==>", error);
      });
  })

  axios
    .get("http/api/words/", {
      headers: { Authorization: cookies.token },
    })
    .then((response) => {
      const cards = response.data;
      setCards(cards);
      getWords(cards);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}, [])
```

Now dependency chain is clearer.